# SharePoint 2016 IT Preview on Azure - responsive?

Tags: responsive, 2016

I was testing out SharePoint 2016 on Azure. I had heard that SharePoint 2016 is going to be responsive. Can someone please tell me how to activate the responsive features on SharePoint 2016? I have been testing it; however, responsive does not seem to work.

Comment: Where did you get that from? The part of it being responsive? I can imagine the nextgen portals might be, but the normal UI probably won't be unless they did some major refactoring outside of Office 365, highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The responsive features can be enabled using the [SharePoint.UI.Responsive](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive) package on GitHub. The responsive UI can be deployed to both SharePoint 2013 and 2016 farms. You can see the [official announcement here](http://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-2016).

Excerpt from the blog:

> We are excited to announce availability of open source Responsive UI
>   Package for SharePoint on-premises. This package is designed to
>   transform your SharePoint on-premises deployment responsive where
>   needed and it supports both SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016
>   version.
>
> Package is available from GitHub and it changes the native behavior of
>   your SharePoint deployment by adding support for three different
>   rendering options depending on the device screen size. You can deploy
>   the package to any on-premises SharePoint site by simply using the
>   provided PowerShell scripts. User interface changes are automatically
>   applied based on the device screen size accessing the SharePoint site.